# Save first mouseposition while 'mouseDragged'

Tags: java, jpanel, mouse-position

I've created a Java-Application to add/remove and show a random number of points on a JPanel. It is possible to move the points per drag&drop. To undo the last actions I buffer the points.

My question: if a point will moved via 'mouseDragged', is it possible to save the first mouseposition while the drag begins? I've tried the following:

```
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    int x = e.getX();
    int y = e.getY();

    if (!points.isEmpty() && curPointIndex > -1) {
        if (move == false) {
            pointmove = new Point(x,y);
            move = true;
        }
    }
}
```

The method `mouseReleased` change the variable `move` back to `false`. The variable `pointmove` should save the first point, but it changes all the time while the mouse is dragged.

Could anyone discribe why or what I can to do differently?

Comment: Maybe you could use `mousePressed` to store the initial point .

Answer (score 0):

As Arnaud mentioned, you can use *mousePressed* to store the initial point:

```
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
        {
            Point initialPoint = e.getPoint();
        }
```